# Process monitoring w/ Haskell angel

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, process, haskell

I'm attempting to monitor a process w/ haskell's angel process monitoring tool. 
https://github.com/MichaelXavier/Angel
The process continues to restart in an infinte loop when it is run w/o receiving any kind of HUP signal.

See below...

```
[2013/12/18 22:25:15] {- program: ls -} RESTART
[2013/12/18 22:25:15] {- program: ls -} START
[2013/12/18 22:25:15] {- program: ls -} Spawning process with env Just []
[2013/12/18 22:25:15] {- program: ls -} RUNNING
[2013/12/18 22:25:15] {- program: ls -} ENDED
[2013/12/18 22:25:15] {- program: ls -} WAITING
[2013/12/18 22:25:22] {- program: ls -} RESTART
[2013/12/18 22:25:22] {- program: ls -} START
[2013/12/18 22:25:22] {- program: ls -} Spawning process with env Just []
[2013/12/18 22:25:22] {- program: ls -} RUNNING
[2013/12/18 22:25:22] {- program: ls -} ENDED
[2013/12/18 22:25:22] {- program: ls -} WAITING
[2013/12/18 22:25:29] {- program: ls -} RESTART
[2013/12/18 22:25:29] {- program: ls -} START
[2013/12/18 22:25:29] {- program: ls -} Spawning process with env Just []
 ... etc
```

It does this for the example app as well as when I try to run my web server.
Here is my conf file (straight from the examples)

```
ls {
    exec = "ls"
    stdout = "/tmp/ls_log"
    stderr = "/tmp/ls_log"
    delay = 7
}
```

I have given angel +x privileges.

Any ideas on why it keeps restarting infinitely?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Once ls finishes, angel will wait 7 seconds and restart it. Once again, ls will finish immediately and angel will wait 7 seconds before repeating...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with

ls_lala
 {
    exec = "ls"
    stdout = "/tmp/ls_log"
    stderr = "/tmp/ls_log"
    delay = 7
}

You may go into infinite loop because you struct name is the same of the app to be executed.

Comment: That is how it is supposed to be I think. In the code above the program ls is actually being executed, I didn't make a new one.